# get pointer position

Tags: c#, windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

I want to make a small box that will be visible after PointerEntered event on bing map. I need to get the position of pointer when the pointer is over the pushpin. Everything works but I can't get the position. I need it so I can dynamicly show the box in correct place near the pushpin.

How can I get cursor/pointer position ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's a good idea trying to rely too much on pointer position in Windows Store apps. Don't forget about your touch based users - how are you going to determine the pointer position in their case?

I haven't used Bing maps and pushpins in a Windows Store app yet, but maybe you could try using [tooltips](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.controls.tooltipservice) instead. They already have built-in support for both touch based and mouse based control and they even position themselves automatically in such a way that the user doesn't obsure them with his finger.

Comment: IMO on touch device you won't invoke PointerEntered cause you can't move your pointer over the point with out tapping it and when you tap you'll invoke tapped event or if you won't move your finger you'll move the map. I'll check the tooltips

Comment: is there a way to modifie the time after which the tooltip is displayed. It is much to slow for me and I can't find way to make it faster

Comment: @Fixus To change the delay before the tooltip is displayed use [InitialShowDelay](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.tooltipservice.initialshowdelay.aspx) attached property.

Comment: i can't use System.Windows.Controls in Windows Store Application. My input comes from Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls and there is no property like you shown

Comment: @Fixus Of course you're right. I wasn't paying enough attention which ToolTipService class I was looking at. Looks like there really is no way to change the delay in Windows Store apps, then. Too bad.